# Error reporting with WMTS

Tags: error, server, wmts

I am looking for information regarding error reporting with WMTS. I have consulted the official documentation at http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts and I found several chapters discussing exceptions. All the information is there, but it is a large document and I am having trouble quickly determining where to look.

I also found this website https://github.com/nasa-gibs/onearth/wiki/WMTS-Response-Codes which gives a clear overview of how an exception should be formatted.

I have two questions. Is the second link the correct way of doing it according to the standard? And does anyone have any more resources explaining WMTS error reporting (Google so far has not helped me).

Comment: Having had a quick look at both documents, I'm not at all certain that the onearth table is clearer than than the specification document.  It does though appear to cover all the Exception codes covered in the specification, and it might be appropriate to say that it is conformant to the standard.

Comment: With the OnEarth sample I got to see some example output right away, I guess that helped me more because I was looking for a quick example. However I will spent some more time getting familiar with the official docs too. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTTP Status Codes**

WMTS errors are a bit of an odd one compared to the other OGC mapping standards (WMS/WFS in particular). In the case of WMS/WFS, when there's an error, an exception is returned in a valid web-page with some variant of XML. The exception usually details what the problem is.

However with WMTS the committee seems to have decided that rather than return an XML exception it should return a more standardised HTTP Status Code symbolising failure instead.

[Wikipedia of course has a complete list of status codes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

You'll want to be looking at the tables which contain the exception codes in the WMTS spec you linked to.

**GetCapabilities**

- Table 20 (page 38) lists exception codes for GetCapabilties requests.
- Table 21 (page 39) then allows you to see which HTTP Status code each one relates to.

**GetTile**

- Table 23 (page 43) lists exception codes for GetTile
- Table 24 (same page) lists which HTTP Status code they correlate to.

**GetFeatureInfo**

- Page 48 - Tables 26 and 27.

The short version is that your response will be a `400 (Client error; bad request)`, `500 (Server Error; Internal Server Error)` or `501 (Server Error; Not Implemented)` depending on the error.

Comment: Thank you for referring to those pages, very helpful. So with WMTS when something goes wrong a corresponding HTTP status code should be returned? Is the status code set alongside an XML string (like the OnEarth example?), or should I only set the HTTP status code? And with WMS the status code is always 200, regardless of success?

Comment: I think the WMTS standard is trying to address possible WMTS implementations.  For example if the WMTS is a RESTful service using HTTP, then the errors must be reported using the HTTP error codes.  If the WMTS implementation is not using HTTP then the HTTP error codes have no meaning and the XML responses are more appropriate.  If the WMTS implementation is using the KVP encoding over HTTP then the service can supply both the HTTP codes and the XML responses...